# Find replacement breaker for generator

Tags: circuit-breaker, generator

I have a bad breaker in my Kohler generator (one pole is open circuit even when switch is "on"). I would like to replace it with an identical breaker. The generator is a Kohler 8.5RES. No longer in production, and I can't find a link on the Kohler website, but some service websites have online manuals.

The breaker seems to be, or be very similar to, a [Square D QOU240 breaker](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/QOU240/mini-circuit-breaker-qou-40a-2-pole-120-240vac-10ka/).

The only difference I can see is that the screws for securing the wire seem to be facing toward the rear on my breaker, whereas all online photos of the QOU240 have the screws facing toward the front of the breaker.

Here are some pictures of my breaker:
[image]

Is there a part number variation with rear facing screws? Or can I somehow pull the cages out and rotate them and put them back in so the screws face toward the rear? I tried to force them out kind of half-heartedly but it doesn't seem like they were meant to come out without permanent damage to the plastic.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Model # of the generator? It might be possible to find a parts diagram/replacement parts list online.

Comment: Oh, wow. That is a good idea. It is a Kohler 8.5RES. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: It is a 40A breaker (based on the picture), which also helps narrow it down.

Comment: In the future, try posting the actual photos, instead of a scrapbook of thumbnails with text added. Put the text in your actual text.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thumbnails? The original photos were huge. I reduced them a bit. Aren't they still perfectly clear? What difference does it make if they are all lumped together in one picture vs several? Yes there is text in the photos, but it is not essential and the question also contains lots of text.

Comment: You reduced them a LOT. Huge helps us see details you don't think are important. If you don't like the file size, then re-save them as JPEG with a lower Q value. Q=3 is fine if the picture is high resolution.

Comment: If you view the full-size image I posted, I doubt you will find it pixelated to any significant degree. But your point is noted, @Harper-ReinstateMonica.

Comment: I probably should have taken the trouble to have less glare though. I will grant you that.

Comment: Sorry if you posted full-size images, I didn't see any.  The biggest picture I saw was about 450px across. Not everyone has a monitor (or eyes) as good as yours.  But I'm glad you got the help you needed.

Comment: Yes 450 pixels. If that is too small I will post bigger pictures next time. Sorry. I don't have good eyes but I have a big screen in front of me.

Comment: I wanted to help but the tiny glarey photos made it really difficult to gather any information from them. On my 4k monitor they are miniscule.

Comment: @KMJ did you click on the image? Then click on the plus to view it full size (in all its 756 horizontal pixel glory)? Anyway I am not arguing. I believe you guys. I will do better next time.

Comment: I did. 784 pixels is only 20% of the width of my screen. Anyway it looks like we solved it, lesson learned for the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the breaker size (40A) and the [generator parts list](https://www.kohlerpower.com/onlinecatalog/pdf/tp5868.pdf), this is Kohler part # **GM24928**. There are a number of places which offer this part. Unfortunately, the definitive source would be Kohler directly, but their parts page appears to be limited to authorized dealers.

The big unknown, of course, is whether this is exactly the same as a standard Square D breaker, except for flipping the screws around, or whether there is something electrically different. My hunch is that the differences are extremely small and purely mechanical, as any electrical changes would affect certification by UL. A 40A breaker is a 40A breaker. But even if the changes are purely mechanical, they could affect safety if using the standard Square D breaker would result in wires getting bent the wrong way or some other strange problem.

Comment: The Square D labeling threw me off the scent of looking for a Kohler part number. I think ordering the Kohler part is the obvious best choice. However, I did stumble upon a variant of the QOU called the QOUR, where the 'R' designates field-reversible lugs. The pictures of that part show the screws facing the back of the breaker. So it is conceivable that the GM24928 is identical to the QOUR240.

Comment: https://www.se.com/us/en/product/QOUR240/mini-circuit-breaker-qou-40a-2-pole-120-240-vac-10ka-field-reversible-lugs/

Comment: @mkeith at least where I am looking the Kohler part is cheaper than the Square-D, too.

Comment: @KMJ that is how it looks to me also. The cheapest place I found for the square D field reversible part is about 2x (even a little more) than ordering the Kohler part from a generator place online.

Comment: The generator is working now with the Kohler part.